# Is the nginx charm stable for production?

Tags: juju, nginx

I'll like to use the nginx charm in production and will like to know if it's stable and ready enough for production.

Yes, I'm talking about specific juju charm for Nginx. I'm talking about this:

http://manage.jujucharms.com/~imbrandon/precise/nginx

Answer (score 2):

No, the nginx charm is not considered production ready yet. An easy way to tell is by looking at the namespace:

It's in `lp:~imbrandon/charms/precise/nginx/trunk`.

That means a person has charmed it, but it hasn't [met the guidelines](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/authors-charm-policy.html) that we expect in the charm store (yet). A production charm would be in `~lp:charms/precise/nginx/trunk` or something like that.

Options here would be to:

- Review the charm yourself and determine if it's production ready, then either fix it to push it into the official store or maintain your own branch.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the nginx main site:

> Nginx is known for its high performance, stability, rich feature set, simple configuration, and low resource consumption.
>
> Nginx powers several high-visibility sites, such as Netflix, Hulu, Pinterest, CloudFlare, Airbnb, WordPress.com, GitHub, SoundCloud, Zynga, Eventbrite, Zappos, Media Temple, Heroku, RightScale, Engine Yard and NetDNA.

I know at least 4 of those sites, and I can vouch they work fantastically well from the user side. Also, the [bug tracker](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/report/1) only has 9 high priority bugs, 5 of them being defects (or in the argot, proper bugs) and [Ubuntu specific bugs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bugs) only 9 bugs, only one of them is of security concern, none about stability.

With all this information, I could say, that nginx is as stable as it could be and usable in production sites.

But if you are talking about a [specific Juju charm](https://jujucharms.com/fullscreen/search/%7Eimbrandon/precise/nginx-7/?provider=aws&provider=openstack&provider=lxc&series=precise&series=raring&series=quantal&text=nginx#bws-summary), you should check the "Quality" tab. It provides more information.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about specific juju charm for Nginx. I'm talking about this: http://manage.jujucharms.com/~imbrandon/precise/nginx